# Is there any way to test bacnet using IPv6 with node

Tags: node.js, npm, ipv6, bacnet

Has anyone used node to test bacnet over ipv6. I'm able to use node-bacnet to verify it via IPv4 with no issues but it does not seem to handle IPv6.
I don't see any other packages that will work with IPv6 but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: You probably need to clarify; are you using 'node-bacnet' as a client or as a server (?).  If as a server, have you tried using 'YABE' as a client (?).

Comment: Sorry mean to get back to you. I've ended up reworking node-bacnet to work with IPv6 for me.

Comment: Probably worth putting a brief answer to your own question, for the benefit of others.